# Javascript interface between Web page and IOS app is not working. Why my app can't receive the messages?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a WKWebView which loads a page. In this page there is a button calls a javascript function. I want this javascript function to send some String data to my app.

This is how my Swift code is built:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit
import WebKit

class TestVC: UIViewController,WKScriptMessageHandler {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Cookies
        let cookie = "document.cookie = '.ASPXAUTH=\(defaults.stringForKey("authKey")!)';"
        let requestUrl = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(MyConstants.WEBURL)")!)
        requestUrl.addValue(".ASPXAUTH=\(defaults.stringForKey("authKey")!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")

        //Settings
        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")
        webViewConfiguration.userContentController = userContentController

        //UI
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(self.view.snp_edges)
        }
        webView.loadRequest(requestUrl)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("got message")
    }


}
```

And this is my javascript:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(json);
```

But when the script is called, nothing is printed on the IOS side. Is there anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with website appearently. The code is working.